Adding a label to a bar chart
I want to add a label to each of the bar generated by the code below.
The labels are defined in a php array $Stamp of same size as $Axe_Min (x axis labels) and $Axe_Alt (y axis data).
I saw that the IndexLabel feature is of some use but I neverfound the proper way to plug it in the code to have the label on top of each bar?
This is an exhibit of the expected result
        <canvas id="Altitude" style="width:100%;max-width:700px"></canvas>
        <script>
            let Altitude = document.getElementById('Altitude').getContext('2d');

            //Global Options
            Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily ='Lato';
            Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize = 18;
            Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor ='#777';

            let Profile = new Chart(Altitude,{
                type:'bar',
                data:{
                    labels:[
                        <?php
                        $etiqs = "";
                        foreach ($Axe_Min as $label) { 
                        $etiqs = $etiqs."'".$label."',"; 
                        }
                        $etiqs = substr($etiqs,0,strlen($etiqs)-1);
                        echo $etiqs;
                        ?>
                        ],
                    datasets:[{
                        label:"Altitude Mer",
                        data:[
                            <?php
                        $values = "";
                        foreach ($Axe_Alt as $value) { 
                        $values = $values."'".$value."',"; 
                        }
                        $values = substr($values,0,strlen($values)-1);
                        echo $values;
                        ?>
                        ],
                        backgroundColor:'green',
                        borderWidth:0,
                        borderColor:'#777'
                    }]
            },
            options:{
                title:{
                    display:true,
                    text:' ',
                    fontSize:25

                },
                legend:{
                    position:'right'
                },
                layout:{
                    padding:{
                        left:50,
                        right:0,
                        bottom:0,
                        top:0
                    }
                },
                tooltips:{
                    enabled:true
                }
            }

            })

            </script>

